# Query on 3 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've three tables in this mode:

**Time1** with column "Data" in format gg/mm/aaaa

**Manual** with columns "valMan" and "dataora" same format.

**Automatic** with columns "valAuto" and "dataora" same format.

I must find values "valAuto" from table Automatic where Data.Time1 is = dataora.Automatic and if the value is null I take this value from valMan.Manual in the same Data.Time1 = dataora.Manual

In access sql or vb for access.

Is very important for me... Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: Sorry. I've another little problem, in colums of Automatic.dataora, I've 4 values: es. 01/01/2010, 01/01/2010 04:00:00, 01/01/2010 08:00:00, 01/01/2010 12:00:00. I need the last: 01/01/2010 12:00:00. But in Time1.Data I've only 01/01/2010 without hours. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MS Access you can try [Iif](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) and [IsNull](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/isnull.php)

```
SELECT  Time1.Data, 
        IIf(IsNull([valAuto]),[valMan],[valAuto]) AS Expr1
FROM    (Time1 LEFT JOIN Automatic ON Time1.Data = Automatic.dataora) LEFT JOIN 
        Manual ON Time1.Data = Manual.dataora;
```

or

[Nz](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php)

```
SELECT  Time1.Data, 
        Nz([valAuto],[valMan]) AS Expr1
FROM    (Time1 LEFT JOIN Automatic ON Time1.Data = Automatic.dataora) LEFT JOIN 
        Manual ON Time1.Data = Manual.dataora;
```

Comment: I've another little problem, in colums of Automatic.dataora, I've 4 values: es. 01/01/2010, 01/01/2010 04:00:00, 01/01/2010 08:00:00, 01/01/2010 12:00:00. I need the last: 01/01/2010 12:00:00. But in Time1.Data I've only 01/01/2010 without hours. How can I do? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about access, but this should do it in MS SQL Server

```
SELECT
ISNULL(a.valAuto, m.valMan) AS whatIWant
FROM
Automatic a
INNER JOIN Time1 t ON a.dataora = t.Data
INNER JOIN Manual m ON t.Data = m.dataora
```

The ISNULL command replaces valAuto with valMan if valAuto is null.

Comment: IsNull() means something completely different in Access/Jet/ACE, so this won't work.

Comment: Okay, didn't know that. Thought that SQL Server and Access might not be that different and that one can at least deduce the solution from it.